# Php XOR хэширование. base64_decode

Tags: php, base64

Нужно простое хеширование эмейла и дэхеширование. Нашел готовую функцию которая это делает на основе base64. Но проблема, которую не знаю как решить, при base64_decode и base64_encode часто выскакивают кракозяблы.

Нашел причину. Часть урл с зашифрованным email имеет вид

```
email=iYMG6aLc+uGXqXN4jX2zApEttnifWUen
```

Когда я достаю этот гет параметр

```
var_dump($email); //iYMG6aLc uGXqXN4jX2zApEttnifWUen
```

исчезает знак `+`в конкретно этом примере. Что это и как с этим бороться? Вот и дешифровка идет не верно

Comment: Но строка которую вы указали: `iIMX7KXc5fyJt3t4imfCJZshvn3dFEulww==` это действительно китайская грамота (ну по крайней мере это иероглифы в UTF-8), а ни какой ни емейл. Указанный вами email в base64 должен быть `dmlraW5nd2l6bGlnaHQxQGdtYWlsLmNvbQ==`  Вы в заголовке что то про xor кодирование писали, может оно еще как то закодировано ?

Comment: P.S. и пожалуйста не используйте термин "дехеширование" потому как Хеширование - это односторонняя функция не подразумевающая обратной операции. Это как восстановить гагабайтный файл на основе его md5. (вот md5 - это нестоящий хеш)

Comment: Не верный пример дал

Comment: А еще base64 может содержать знаки равно в конце и `/` которые в принципе не должны сильно портить передачу. главное что бы php знаки `=` не посчитал не относящимися к этой переменной. А вообще в URL знак + означает пробел. Так что самое простое - при получении строки заменить все пробелы на знаки `+`.  или заранее перед кодированием URL знаки + менять например на `_` и при получении менять обратно

Comment: Благодарю за помощь